# Spring Boot - Actuator Metrics Endpoint not working in docker image

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, micrometer

In my Spring Boot App Yaml  I have :

```
 management:
  metrics:
    export:
      simple:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

However, when i hit

```
localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
```

its working in spring boot standalone app, but in the docker image the endpoint  actuator/metrics doesnt work and it redirect me to the default page, the app still works fine.

My docker file :

```
  FROM openjdk:11-jre-buster

RUN apt update && apt install curl -y \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


MAINTAINER  xxxxx
ARG VERSION

ENV SERVER_PORT 80
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1g

# add this to solve buster sso issue
ENV OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl

ENV SPRINGPROFILES=actuator

WORKDIR /app
COPY maven/docker-package/ /app

# Tesseract installation
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https && \
    echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/buster/ buster main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update -oAcquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true && \
    apt-get install notesalexp-keyring -oAcquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install tesseract-ocr 

EXPOSE ${SERVER_PORT}

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=5s --retries=3 \
      CMD curl -f http://localhost:80/actuator/health || exit 1

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh :

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dlicense.path=/app/licenses/ "-Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRINGPROFILES}" -Dlogging.config=/app/config/log4j2.xml -Dserver.port=80 -jar /app/app-executable.jar
```

what am i missing? is there any configuration needs to be done to expose the metrics in docker ? thanks for your responses.

Comment: Since it is not working on docker, it would be beneficial if you share the docker command/docker file you are using to run it.

Comment: I just edited it with docker file i run with , thanks for your help

Comment: What happens if you log into the container and run the command you’re running locally?

Comment: hey @AbhijitSarkar the actuator isnt exposed so i cant see my metrics as i see them locally, it redirect me into my default page!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Spring Boot Actuator in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052732/use-spring-boot-actuator-in-docker)

Comment: have you tried to run it with docker run -e SPRINGPROFILES=actuator ... ?

Comment: yes tried it, doesnt work , i just made it work now, my problem was in the application.yml wasnt configurable for docker image but only for the app! i just posted the answer, thanks everyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

copying the application.yml under Config directory and setting it into my configDir of my app and then moving it into the image solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

you should open port on run docker :

```sh
sudo docker run **** 8080/8080 *****
```

Comment: yes i do run it with docker run -p 8080:80 --name hex imagename, and it works fine just as in the standalone , but with no /actuator/metrics

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `actuator` profile:

```
environment:
      - "SPRINGPROFILES=prod,actuator"
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052732/use-spring-boot-actuator-in-docker/54071383).

Comment: i tried doing it from my docker file its not working , and i dont have a docker-compose file in my project, should i just create it ? under which directory ? thanks for your help